# Number of users tagged in comments

Tags: feature-request

I've felt need to tag more than one person (other than OP) in many of the comments in posts on SO. Why is it that number of users that can be tagged in a comment has been restricted to 1?

If there is some reason to this, I'd like to know that or else, I request the SO team to add this new feature so that more than one user can be tagged in a comment.

Comment: [Related Meta.SE FAQ on @comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/175248)

Answer (score 6):

I've also felt the need, on occasion, to notify more than one person when commenting. And then I slapped myself, and remembered that comments are *not* the place for extended discussion.

If you wish to have a conversation with a bunch of people about a question/answer then you should get those people in to a chat room. That is what they are for.

Comment: If that is the case, for every question, we would need a chat room. A short discussion regarding (maybe) a doubt what OP has asked or something does not need a chat room IMO. eg. I felt a need to tag 2 users in the comment on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932929/what-is-the-bug-in-the-following-code (See last of my comments in the question) and there is no discussion whatsoever.

Comment: _"for every question, we would need a chat room."_ Nope. We really don't.

Comment: @Cerbrus, not literally, of course.

Comment: @vish4071 I think you're missing the point, for a vanishingly small number of questions you *might* need a chat room. For the huge (as in massive) majority, you don't. Also the example you gave is a perfect example of "if you want to help that user ask a better question, get them in a chat room". Ive done this a few times, and its infinitely easier to help a new user that way than have a long, protracted conversation in comments.